# Function watching in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I want to log the entry and exit from every method in my code. Specifically I want to log the function name and timestamp at function entry and function name, timestamp and return value at function exit. It is possible to do this with gdb
(Reference: Please look at the following question and the accepted answer - [Tool to trace local function calls in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux)). Does VS debugger allow me to do this?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981440/use-c-attribute-to-track-function-call-variables-and-return-value

Comment: @FractalizeR: C++ with Win32API

Answer (score 1):

I think the preffered way to do this now a days is to use **IntelliTrace**. If you tune it to gather enough information, it will provide a report with all the functions calls, parameters etc.